# Average from an array?

Tags: arrays, c, average

Task description:

> The Dutch conquer territory from the sea with dams and do not like to
> be crossed by these dams the waves. The renovation of an old dam is
> planned as follows. A is measured at a point in front of the dam the
> height of the waves and then take the waves that strike (i.e., those
> that are higher than the at the current dam) and the average height of
> these waves will be the new dam height. For example, if you have one
> 20-meter dam, and waves [12, 32, 16, 40, 21] meters high are measured
> in front of it, then the 2nd, 4th, and 5th pins, their values ​​are
> 32, 40, 21, the average of which is (32 + 40 + 21) / 3 = 31, ie the
> new dam must be 31 meters. Write a function that calculates the new
> dam height. The first input parameter is a whole a standing array
> whose terminating element is 0. This contains the height of the waves.
> The other input parameter is current dam height, which is an integer.
> The function is the integer part of the average of the waves higher
> than the barrier returns. If no waves pass, the function returns the
> height of the original dam. int average (int input [], int height);

My code is:

```
int average(int input[], int height){
    int counter = 0;
    int added = 0;
    int average;

    for(int i = 0; input[i] != '0'; i++)
        if(input[i]>height) {
            added += input[i];
            counter++;
        }

    average = added/counter;

    return average;
}
```

The problem is that when I run the code, I got this error message:

> Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

I've looked into this for unauthorized memory usage, but I can't figure out what's causing this.

I got the answer thanks to you guys.:

```
if (counter != 0) {
        average = added / counter;
        return average;
    } else {
        return height;
    }
```

That's it, my problem was dividing by 0.

Comment: please post code that we can try out, this has no main in it

Comment: @bcseh202 Does the passed array contain an element equal to 0?

Comment: You're comparing `input[i]` against `'0'` rather than `0`; perhaps that's the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can’t post the full code because I have to upload the code shown here into a special system, but every other part that the machine tests is encrypted for me.
However, I can see the first test case, which is as follows:
{(dam height:) 20, {12, 32, 16, 40, 21, 0}, (new dam height:) 31}

Yes, the character 0 always closes the array, as you can see from the test case above.

That’s why I compare it to ‘0’ because it’s a character if I know well. But I just tried it, it doesn't work without quotes.

Comment: `'0'` and `0` are different. One is an ascii character and one is an int. You want the latter (remove the single quotes).

Comment: `average = added/counter;` This can get a divide by zero error if `counter` is never incremented.

Comment: Thanks for the help!
I rewrote it without the quotation marks and after answering kaylum I modified the code as described above.

Answer (score 0):

The array has whats called a sentinel value. Ie a special value that marks the end. It is a value of 0. But you are not testing for it correctly

```
   for(int i = 0; input[i] != '0'; i++)
```

you mean

```
   for(int i = 0; input[i] != 0; i++)
```

why?

In C '0' is a character. Characters will be treated as integers in almost all placed where an integer is expected. But it is a direct translation of the ASCII value of the character. See here https://www.asciitable.com/

You see that the character '0' is actually decimal 48, hex 0x32, *not* 0.